# Can I use this google finance graph for my website?

Tags: finance

Can I use this google finance graph for my website ?

http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_ZaGO7GjCqAI/SKLQYz3h-cI/AAAAAAAAJ-Q/CMScCQuWW1M/s640/plot-feeds-in-google-finance.png

Answer (score 1):

Yes checkout the [google finance api](http://code.google.com/apis/finance/). If yu are more specific then we can help you more.

Answer (score 1):

I hereby grant you the permission to do so.