# Get stock value from google return as a string

Tags: jquery

I have an address that displays the current value of a stock.  For instance Apple

http://www.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NASDAQ:AAPL

Is there a way with jQuery to call this site and have the content return as a string

Comment: As this is not JSONP service, you must use server side code to send the request, you can't do it with pure client side code due to [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: And make sure Google actually allows third parties to access and display that data.

Comment: All I need is to show the stock value for a single company on there website.  I was planning on updating it using a timer or anytime the page loads.  Is there any technique that can be used to get the stock price?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Can I use this google finance graph for my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482928/can-i-use-this-google-finance-graph-for-my-website)

However the Google Finance API is deprecated (but working for the time being).

Also Google Gadgets provides countless third party financial gadgets:  http://www.google.com/ig/directory?synd=open&cat=finance

And I'm sure there are plenty of other sites other than Google, that provide the same or similar.